# Run into a python error <generator object <genexpr>

Tags: python, list, nested, set

When I run

```
a = ["I","love","you"]
a = {(word) for word in a}
print a
```

I get this result

```
set(['I', 'you', 'love'])
```

and that's what I expect.

But when I run

```
a = ["I","love","you"]
a = {((word) for word in c)for c in a}
print a
```

I get some unexpected result:

```
set([<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d5280>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d5320>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1004d5370>])
```

And what I expect is

```
set(['e','I','u','o','v','l','y')
```

Can anybody tell my the reason that causes this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Does your expected result have extra `[` or missing `]`? If you just want the set of all letters you would do `{c for w in a for c in w}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a syntax issue. `(word)` is equivalent to `word`. However, when you include a `for` loop in an expression surrounded by parentheses, it is considered a generator expression ([PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)).

Instead, use a nested loop directly:

```
res = {word for c in a for word in c}

# {'I', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'u', 'v', 'y'}
```

The syntax is analogous to a regular `for` loop:

```
res = set()
for c in a:
    for word in c:
        res.add(word)
```

Comment: yeah～I just accept it.Thanks a lot.This is the first time I post question on stackoverflow and I feel so good